# How to call a class method using ajax in c#

Tags: c#, ajax

I have a class in my c# project. Let's say **Sample.cs**
I want to call it's method using ajax, but don't know how to use class name in url of ajax, I am doing like this, but it's not working

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Sample.cs/MethodName",
                    data: '{Id: "' + Id + '"}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
}
});
```

Please Help Guys...

Comment: If that would work you may access ANY method on a webservice via a simple HTTP-call. You need to adress the aspx-page instead of the cs-file to achieve this.

Comment: an aspx page or a controller (MVC/Web API) is needed to be able to make a HTTP request. Without it you have no endpoint to call from the javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you directly want to call a method of a class, you cannot. 
You can only make HTTP requests calls.

If you are using, MVC, what you can do is that create an Action method with return type as `JsonResult`, (*as from you snippet, it looks you are expecting json response*) call your method from this action method and return the same. Or you can create WebApi services and call that method within the `ApiController` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a WCF Rest service and call it from your js.
You create a method in an interface in C# which will react to your Http request

Here's an example

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", //React on GET method
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, //Return Json format
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, //Wrap request and response
            UriTemplate = "login/{id}/{mdp}")] //Template Uri
    bool Login(string id, string mdp);
```

This method will be called if you receive a GET method on an url like 
SERVER_NAME/login/myId/myPassword

Note : all your parameters must be of type string

If you don't know what is a REST service here's some links
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)

If you want to learn how to create a REST webService in C# :
[codeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide)

Sadly I don't have enough point to post more link...

Hope it helped !

Comment: Here's another link to learn how to create a Rest webservice  
http://www.topwcftutorials.net/2013/09/simple-steps-for-restful-service.html